# Retrieve specific value from Setter and Getter method inside Chaining methods using Java

Tags: java, object, setter, getter, method-chaining

I am trying to get specific value from setter method using java method chaining.
like if we do obj.setId(1).setValue(5).
how we can get value = 5 using obj.setId(1).getValue();

here is the main class

```
public class MenuDish {

    private String name;
    private double price;
    private String description;
    private int category;
    private  int spiciness;
    private boolean healthy;

    public MenuDish(){ //constrcutor

    }

    public MenuDish setPrice(double price){

        if(price < 0.0){
            this.price = 0.0;
        }
        else{
            this.price = price;
        }
        return this;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

    public MenuDish setDay(int day){

    return new MenuDish();//just do nothing 
}

}
```

Sub class

**AdjustableMenuDish Class**

```
public class AdjustableMenuDish extends  MenuDish {
    private int day;
    private double price;

        public AdjustableMenuDish(){ //constructor
        setName(null);
        setPrice(0);
        setDescription(null);
        setCategory(0);
        setHealthy(false);
        setSpiciness(0);
    }

    @Override
    public MenuDish setDay(int day){

        this.day = day;
        return this;
    }

}
```

Inside main method I am trying to do something like this.

```
AdjustableMenuDish dish = new AdjustableMenuDish();
dish.setDay(0).setPrice(3.4);
dish.setDay(3).setPrice(7.4);
System.out.println(dish.setDay(0).getPrice());//--->output 7.4 but how to
get 3.4 instead of 7.4
```

Basically I am trying to get specific price from day.

**Edit**

I want to pass Junit test case which is given below

```
@Test public void test_daily_prices() {
      AdjustableMenuDish dish = new AdjustableMenuDish();
      for (int i = MenuDish.MONDAY; i <= MenuDish.SUNDAY;  i++) {
          double p = 1.0+i;

          double a = dish.setDay(i).setPrice(p).getPrice();

          assertEquals(p, a, 0.0001);
     }

      for (int i = MenuDish.MONDAY; i <= MenuDish.SUNDAY;  i++) {
          double p = 1.0+i;
          double a = dish.setDay(i).getPrice();
          assertEquals(p, a, 0.0001);
      }
  }
```

> Fail expected 1.0 but was 7.0

Comment: You are overwriting the previous value with the latest entered one, you'll need to store the data in an array to retrieve unique data

Answer (score 2):

You need to pair days and prices together, rather than have them as single attributes of `MenuDish`. You could try something like:

```
class AdjustableMenuDish {
    private double[] prices = new double[7]; // Assumes day as [0..6]
    ...
    public AdjustableMenuDish setPrice(int day, double price) {
        prices[day] = price;
        return this;
    }
    public double getPrice(int day) {
        return prices[day];
    }
}
```

If every dish has a different price depending on the day, then this code could be in `MenuDish`. If it's only some dishes, then it probably belongs on `AdjustableMenuDish`.

Given that a *price* is really a *price per day*, I think you should submit the two together, ie. in one method (as above). If you really want to stick to your `MenuDish` API as it is now, then you could try something like the following. This tracks the current day.

```
class MenuDish {
    private double[] prices = new double[7]; // Assumes day as [0..6]
    private int day;
    ...
    public MenuDish setDay(int day) {
        this.day = day;
        return this;
    }
    public MenuDish setPrice(double price) {
        prices[day] = price;
        return this;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return prices[day];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Exteam I've reviewed your edits and come up with another solution. I haven't tested it, but I think it should work.

Comment: OK. Does that mean your not allowed to use them yet? We could use arrays if you like.

Comment: @Exteam I've updated my answer to use an array instead of a HashMap.